# Renaming multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, automation, sql-update, ddl

My table has a bunch of columns in the following format:

```
_settingA
_settingB
_settingB
```

And I want to rename them simply to add a prefix as follows:

```
_1_settingA
_1_settingB
_1_settingC
```

I have a *lot* more than three columns to rename in this way.  If I had just three, I'd just do it manually one by one.

What is the quickest / most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49520887/124486

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no single command aproach. Obviously you could type multiple comands for `RENAME` by your self, but let me intoduce some improvement:) As I said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266974/5404196)

> ...for all such bulk-admin-operations you could use PostgreSQL system tables to generate queries for you instead of writing them by hand

In your case it would be:

```
SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE ' || tab_name || ' RENAME COLUMN '
    || quote_ident(column_name) || ' TO '
    || quote_ident( '_1' || column_name) || ';'
FROM (
    SELECT
        quote_ident(table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(table_name) as tab_name,
        column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns  
    WHERE 
            table_schema = 'schema_name'
            AND table_name = 'table_name'
            AND column_name LIKE '\_%'
) sub;
```

That'll give you set of strings which are SQL commands like:

```
ALTER TABLE  schema_name.table_name RENAME COLUMN "_settingA" TO "_1_settingA";
ALTER TABLE  schema_name.table_name RENAME COLUMN "_settingB" TO "_1_settingB";
...
```

There no need using `table_schema` in `WHERE` clause if your table is in `public` schema. **Also remember using function `quote_ident()`** -- read my original answer for more explanation.

Edit:

I've change my query so now it works for all columns with name begining with underscore `_`. Because underscore is special character in SQL pattern matching, we must escape it (using `\`) to acctually find it.

Comment: Regarding the following part: `AND column_name IN ('_settingA', '_settingB', '_settingC')` is there a way to specify that generically rather than having to list each explicitly (there are a lot), so that it operates on any column name beginning with `_`?

Comment: Yes, just change `AND column_name IN ('_settingA', '_settingB', '_settingC')` into `AND column_name LIKE '\\_%'`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Can't quite get this to work.  I'm replacing `schema_name` with `public` and `table_name` with `test`, since these match the table's schema and name.  That gives me a syntax error which seems to be solved by removing the `;` from the first `SELECT`.  But then I get `ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias / LINE 5: FROM ( / HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo`.  I've tried to follow the hint, but still can't get a working solution.

Comment: I am sorry i'd correct the query. You were righ. Firstly `;` after first `SELECT` shouldn't be there. Seccondly subquery must have an alias (which I added `sub`). There was also third mistake in escaping character in `LIKE` clause -- there must be only one `\\`.

Comment: OK, great.  I understand a bit more about your method: executing this does not actually update the column names, but instead generates the queries required to do so.  That's clever, and it works.  One suggestion for improvement: add `|| ';'` at the end of the first `SELECT` so that you can copy/paste the strings directly without further editing.  (I can see that your original answer *tried* to include this but it was interpreted as a literal `;` rather than as a string `';'`)

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this will work.

```
SELECT FORMAT(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I.%I RENAME %I TO %I;',
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  column_name,
  '_PREFIX_' + column_name
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'foo';
```

`%I` will do `quote_ident`, which is substantially nicer. If you're in PSQL you can run it with `\gexec`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function : 
*(I use this to add prefix on tables wiches have more than 50 columns)*

First create the function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rename_cols( schema_name_ text,table_name_ text, prefix varchar(4))
    RETURNS bool AS
     $BODY$
     DECLARE
       rec_selection record;
        BEGIN
          FOR rec_selection IN (
              SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = schema_name_ AND table_name = table_name_) LOOP
            EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE '||schema_name_||'.'||table_name_||' RENAME COLUMN "'|| rec_selection.column_name ||'" TO "'||prefix|| rec_selection.column_name ||'" ;';
          END LOOP;
        RETURN True;
       END;
     $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
```

Then execute function :

```
SELECT rename_cols('public','test','d');
```

Hope it will be usefull,

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that.

All the actions except **RENAME** and **SET SCHEMA** can be combined into a list of multiple alterations to apply in parallel.

most efficient way is using ActiveRecord.