# postgres execute sql in resulting rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, exec, rows

postgesql 9.6.17

There are result rows from [Renaming multiple columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401404/renaming-multiple-columns-in-postgresql/33410731)

they contain some commands like

```
alter table .....
alter table .....
```

how to immediately exec them in sql like

```
SELECT
    EXEC SQL 'ALTER TABLE ' || tab_name || ' RENAME COLUMN '
    || quote_ident(column_name) || ' TO '
    || lower(quote_ident( column_name)) || ';' commit
FROM (
    SELECT
        quote_ident(table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(table_name) as tab_name,
        column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns  
    WHERE 
            table_schema = 'public'
) sub;
```

but example ↑ fails

Comment: I think you mean `EXECUTE` Also: your code is incomplete and cannot be tested.

Comment: example is fully complete. i want to do lower() for all column names of all my tables, so i got an alter table - query in rows, but it is huge, and i ask, how to execute them in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DO statement for executing this. Something like given below:

```
DO $$
DECLARE rec TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOR rec in SELECT
            'ALTER TABLE ' || tab_name || ' RENAME COLUMN '
            || quote_ident(column_name) || ' TO '
            || lower(quote_ident( column_name))
          FROM (
              SELECT
                  quote_ident(table_schema) || '.' || 
                  quote_ident(table_name) as tab_name,
                  column_name
                  FROM information_schema.columns  
              WHERE 
                   table_schema = 'public'
            ) sub
  LOOP
    EXECUTE rec;
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

For more detail refer the following link:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-do.html

Comment: just please fix, instead FOR r in SELECT there should be  FOR rec in SELECT

Comment: please update to use `rec`