# How to batch create index on 1000 tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a parent table called ABC  in postgres 9.3 db

and about 1000 tables inherit ABC

```
ABC_1
ABC_2
...
ABC_1002
```

since index on parent table doesn't affect child table, I have to create indexes on them separately.

Is there any batch way to automate index creating on these tables ?

Comment: Hi! Do you have table per date/user?

Comment: A loop with some dynamic sql should be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your tables are really named as in the question (I mean enumeration "_1", "_2") etc. Then that simple query will generate set of `CREATE INDEX` for you.

```
SELECT
    'CREATE INDEX ON ' || quote_ident('ABC_' || sub.num ) || ' (column_name);' 
FROM
    (SELECT num FROM generate_series(1,1000) num) sub;
```

But honestly I expect that you provide only simplified example, so please check this two answers of mine about using `SQL` to DDL commands generation ([first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410731/5404196), [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266974/5404196)) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461750/5404196) to learn how to get list of child relations from system tables.